# An extension to enable or disable images in chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I can change the chrome setting by going to Privacy and security - site settings - Content section - disable Images

Is there a chrome extension that will do exactly that? I have tried 2 extensions, but both of them remove images "after" they have loaded. That does not make browsing any faster. I will like to click a button to enable / disable the setting mentioned above.

Comment: You can write your own extension that uses [chrome.contentSettings](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings#type-ImagesContentSetting), which shouldn't be too hard if you modify one of the official [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:contentSettings). Note that looking for existing extensions is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Chrome extension that lets you disable/enable images on "per host" level.Click once and you'll disable images for the current site. Click again and images will be re-enabled.

https://singleclickapps.com/images-on-off/

There are some options available, but basically, the extension does just that (and nothing more)